# How to assign namespaced controller/view to logged in user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm pondering over what would be the best solution for the following scenario:

We have a basic website which everybody can navigate without sign up/sign in. The controllers and views live under app/controllers and app/views/model_name.

When the user signs up and logs in (with devise) she should be redirected to a different controller under app/users/ and correspondingly to different views under app/views/users/.

I know, I could render different partials based on `signed_in?` from my views and I could also redirect from the default controller to the controller nested under the `user` directory, but I feel there must a more general approach.

I'm wondering if it could be done with routing alone (and of course having the directory structure with the different controller/view pairs in place).

Example:

```
app/
  controllers/
    albums_controller.rb
    users/
      albums_controller.rb

  views/
    albums/
      index.rb
    users/
      albums/
        index.rb
```

**Edit:** I [rewrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402705/route-devise-to-different-controller-view-set) this post being a little bit more specific and got pointed towards the [solution](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out) which consisted in overriding `after_sign_in_path_for`.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways:

- Combine a [redirection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection) with a [custom constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints/)
- Create a sub-class of `ApplicationController`:

  ```
  class SignedOutApplicationController < ApplicationController
    before_action :redirect_if_signed_in
    ...
  end
  ```

  and make it the sub-class for all of the non-user controllers. For symmetry I would create a `SignedInController`